# Path shortener for GUI application

Tags: python, strings, file-system

I need to display a path within a GUI application. Displaying the whole path would be an overkill, so I made a custom path shortener.

```
def cut_path(path):
    ''' This function takes a path and outputs the path cut with the ... after the 
     the first folder after the first character and completes the name with the filename or the last folder
    Example: 
    C:/Users/Mauro/Desktop/DenoiseAvg/DenoiseAverage/test_cut_path.py
    C:/Users/.../test_cut_path.py
     '''      
    endidx = 5
    char = path[endidx]    
    while char != '/' and endidx < len(path):
        endidx += 1
        char = path[endidx]

    inpath = path[:endidx + 1 ]

    rpath = path[::-1]    
    idx = 1   
    char = rpath[idx]    
    while char != "/" and idx < len(rpath):
        idx += 1
        char = rpath[idx]

    endpath = path[len(path) - idx - 1 : ]

    outpath = inpath + "..." + endpath
    return outpath
```

[Pastebin for syntax highlighting](https://pastebin.com/aefj8b6G)

Is there a shorter, more readable, pythonic way to do it? Is there a way to limit how many characters the path would be long? How would you do it?

Comment: Why not use “…” (U+2026, horizontal ellipsis) instead of “...”?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Python is 'batteries included'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Libraries), this means offloading code to the core library is a good thing, and often possible. In this case, if you're running Python 3.4+ you could make use of [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). All you need is to know the [`pathlib.PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath) constructor and [`PurePath.parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts).

And so you can change your code to:

```
import pathlib

def cut_path(path):
    parts = list(pathlib.PurePath(path).parts)
    if len(parts) >= 4:
        parts [2:-1] = ['...']
    return pathlib.PurePath(*parts)
```

---

However, as you're doing it on how long the path is, you could dynamically build the new path. And so could use something like:

```
def cut_path(path, max_size=5):
    if not path:
        return path

    parts = list(pathlib.PurePath(path).parts)

    path = pathlib.PurePath(parts[0])
    for part in parts[1:-1]:
        path /= part
        if len(str(path)) >= max_size:
            path /= '...'
            break
    if len(parts) > 1:
        path /= parts[-1]
    return path
```

---

If however you're using Python 2 or Python <3.4 then you can't use the nice new interface, and would have to use the old interface, [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html). Which doesn't support splitting and joining the paths very well. First you may want to use [`os.path.normcase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase) to normalize the path. Which may destroy the path if you have a Posix path on Windows. After this you'd want to take the drive with [`os.path.splitdrive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive), and then split the rest of the parts using `os.sep`. Then you want to do the same as above, and replace the middle section of the path, and finally [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) them all together.

Which could leave you with something like:

```
def cut_path(path):
    path = os.path.normcase(path)
    drive, path = os.path.splitdrive(path)
    parts = path.split(os.sep)
    parts[0] = drive + parts[0]
    # Join plays funny, so you have to add a separator in these cases.
    if parts[0][-1] == ':':
        parts[0] += os.sep
    if len(parts) >= 4:
        parts [2:-1] = ['...']
    return os.path.join(*parts)
```

Comment: Though I prefer your solution. I would point out it generated a different result to the original code. Yours has a minimum of 4 segments. The original had a minimum of 4 characters.

Comment: @LokiAstari Oh my bad. Thank you for telling me, I'll look into fixing that now, :)

Answer (score 7):

Rather than hardcoding a `/` it would be more os agnostic to use `os.path.sep` for the separator.

Answer (score 3):

No I don't think that is idiomatic python (though I am not the perfect person to answer the question).

I think it is more idiomatic to split the string (into an array). Then use the parts of the array to build the result.

There also seems to be a bug in your for short paths:

```
cut_path("c:/a/a.y")
```

This is how I would do it

```
def cut_path2(path):
    segments = path.split('/')
    siz = 0
    pat = 0
    output = ""

    # Your code assumes the prefix must be at least 
    # 5 characters long I record this in siz
    while (siz < 5) and (pat < len(segments)):
        output += segments[pat]
        output += "/"
        siz += len(segments[pat]) + 1
        pat += 1

    # You don't want to shorten if the
    # the first loop prints the whole path.
    if pat < (len(segments)):
        output += ".../"
    if pat <= (len(segments)):
        output += segments[len(segments) - 1]    
    return output
```

It tested this with the unit test you provided but I can guarantee that it will work for all paths.